# Can we use resilient4j like dependency as circuit breaker or ratelimit for database calls?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, circuit-breaker

I have an reporting application which nightly runs some job, In order to avoid load on database, Can I try using features like resilient4j to tackle such situation?

FYI, I have spring boot scheduler as application.

I was experimenting few things like keeping track of # queries executed by scheduler job etc manually, But i need some suggestion on this problem from community.

Comment: yes you can use it you probably need to try it